# Return value in DropDownMenu on selection?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Xcode and Swift. I am using this library: https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu to create DropDownMenu in my app. I followed the demo from Github and everything works fine. I am trying to get the selected value and assign it to a string outside **didSelectItemAtIndexHandler** function. This is my code:

```
 var menuView: BTNavigationDropdownMenu!

 var items = ["San Francisco", "New York", "LA", "Chicago"]


 menuView = BTNavigationDropdownMenu(navigationController: self.navigationController, containerView: self.navigationController!.view, title: BTTitle.index(0), items: items)

    menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = {(indexPath: Int) -> Void in

        self. myCity = items[indexPath]
        //print(myCity) // prints the correct city every time
    }

 self.navigationItem.titleView = menuView
```

I am trying to get the following outside **menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler** :

```
 var test = String()
 test = myCity
 print(test)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I am trying to pass the data from here to TopFiveViewController.

```
 menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = {(indexPath: Int) -> Void in

 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main) 
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TopFiveViewController") as! TopFiveViewController 
 vc.myCity = self!.items[indexPath]
 print(myCity) // prints the correct city every time but it doesn't pass the value to TopFiveViewController!

}
```

In the TopFiveViewController I have:

```
var myCity = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      if self.myCity == "San Francisco" {

        // load SF json file

    } else if myCity == "New York" {

        // load NY json file

      }
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan Everything is in didViewLoad. When I print(test) nothing prints.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that everything is happening in your `viewDidLoad()` I think it's important to understand what is happening.

The view loads and `test` as well as `myCity` are set to `nil`.

When the user selects an item from the dropdown menu the code within `menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler` will be called and `myCity` will now be set to the selected value although `test` will still be `nil` as the completion handler setting the value of `myCity` has no effect on `test`.

You should execute whatever code you want to execute when the value is selected within the completion handler (where `self. myCity = items[indexPath]` is located).

Comment: I know the code that I have to execute will happened inside completion handler but my question is if I can take the value and use it outside? Has to be executed outside **menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler**  I hope it makes sense?!! Thanks.

Comment: @Dian May I ask why you want to use the variable outside of `menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler`? You should be able to create a function to do whatever you want and then call it from the completion handler.

Comment: I am trying to pass the value of self.myCity to another VC. When everything is executed inside menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler the app breaks!

Comment: I am using ACTabScrollView! I have a table view that goes to 5 different VC. Trying to pass the value selected with the myCity and send data to each VC.

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TopFiveViewController") as! TopFiveViewController
                vc.myCity = self!.items[indexPath]   ..... it does't pass the data!